# React MUI Slider OnChangeCommitted doesn't slide

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, slider

So I'm trying to use the Material UI slider in React. But the problem was that when I used the `OnChange` it triggered the function every time the value changed. I only wanted it to trigger when the left mouse button is up. Than I realized there was a feature for that:

Called `OnChangeCommitted`:
https://mui.com/material-ui/api/slider/

The problem now is that the ball doesn't slide anymore. With **only** `OnChange` the ball used to slide, but now the ball only moves when I let go of the mouse button. This is the way I'm using it right now:

```
// In the render/return
<Slider
    defaultValue={defaultValue}
    value={parseFloat(sliderValue)}
    step={0.1}
    marks={marks}
    valueLabelDisplay="on"
    onChangeCommitted={sliderChange} 
    sx={{color: theme.palette.secondary.main}}
    //onChange={sliderChange} 
    // I could not find a way to detect left mouse button up to make an 
    // if(leftMouseButton == up) { make API call }
    // else { //do nothing } 
/>

// The function
const sliderChange = (event, newValue) => {
    console.log("new slider value: " + newValue)
    setSliderValue(newValue);
    axios.get(uri + "/" + newValue, { headers: auth }).then((res) => {
        setObjectsEtcEtc(res.data);
    })
};
```

(My) Solution:

After looking at it for a while there was indeed a way to catch the mouseup.

```
<Slider
    defaultValue={defaultValue}
    value={parseFloat(sliderValue)}
    step={0.1}
    marks={marks}
    valueLabelDisplay="auto"
    sx={{ color: cimTheme.palette.secondary.main }}
    onChange={sliderChange}  // change slider value + slider value state and nothing else
    onMouseUp={() => { 
        commitSliderValue(); //commit slider value when mouse up
    }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `onChange` and `onChangeCommitted` have an event in their arguemnts. But the difference is that the `onChange` only catches `mosedown` and `mousemove` events, but the `onChangeCommitted` only runs when `mouseup` event is triggered.
So you can use a mixture of these functions for your purposes like this:

```
<Slider
  defaultValue={defaultValue}
  value={parseFloat(sliderValue)}
  step={0.1}
  marks={marks}
  valueLabelDisplay="on"
  onChangeCommitted={handleChangeCommited}
  onChange={handleChange}
  sx={{ color: theme.palette.secondary.main }}
/>;

//call api when mouse is up
const handleChangeCommited = (
  event: React.SyntheticEvent | Event,
  newValue: number | Array<number>
) => {
  axios.get(uri + "/" + (newValue as number), { headers: auth }).then((res) => {
    setObjectsEtcEtc(res.data);
  });
};

// change the value when mouse is down or moving
const handleChange = (event: Event, newValue: number | number[]) => {
  setSliderValue(newValue as number);
};
```

Comment: After looking at my code and figuring out that `when mouse up happens outside of slider component` than the commit code won't be executed. So you're code is way better, thanks! Also that `: React.SyntheticEvent | Event` is typescript I think, so I didn't understand the code before.

Comment: @zhrgci Glad to help you. And yes, that's for typescript, you can avoid that if you're working with java script.